# How to Map RegEx variables with BodyData fetched from CSV Files

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

CSV Data Config from JMeter contains following - 
[image: CSV Data Config]

File.csv Contains following
[image: Common Data File]

GetAllOrderItems.txt contains following

```
{"dataRows":[],"orderGuid":"${orderGuid_1_g1}","facilityPk":"0","jtStartIndex":0,"jtPageSize":100,"jtSorting":"SKU ASC","isMap":"1"}
```

orderGuid_1_g1 is fetched from Regular Expression extractor
[image: JMeter Reg Ex]

I passed following to JMeter body data
[image]

When I execute JMeter test, I can see follwing

```
{"dataRows":[],"orderGuid":"${orderGuid_1_g1}","facilityPk":"0","jtStartIndex":0,"jtPageSize":100,"jtSorting":"SKU ASC","isMap":"1"}
```

However, I want ${orderGuid_1_g1} to be fetched from Reg Ex of previous HTTP Request.
I want following

```
  {"dataRows":[],"orderGuid":"644e1dd7-2a7f-18fb-b8ed-ed78c3f92c2b","facilityPk":"0","jtStartIndex":0,"jtPageSize":100,"jtSorting":"SKU ASC","isMap":"1"}
```

Code works well, If i did not fetch Body data from text and directly insert below code inside body of HTTP Request

```
    {"dataRows":[],"orderGuid":"${orderGuid_1_g1}","facilityPk":"0","jtStartIndex":0,"jtPageSize":100,"jtSorting":"SKU ASC","isMap":"1"}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JMeter does not interpret variables when you load content from a file.

Besides, for a load test **using [__FileToString](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function is not advised unless it is used for setup for example which is not the case here.**

So just put the JSON Body request in the request body, it will be better for readability.

If you still want to do that, follow Dmitri Answer.

Comment: Inside Body Parameter, I write ${__FileToString(${GetAllOrderItems-FacilityPkIsZero},,)}"orderGuid":"${orderGuid_1_g1}"} and it works fine. Is it better way for load testing or directly putting JSON body request inside body like {"dataRows":[], "orderGuid":"${orderGuid_1_g1}","facilityPk":"0", "jtStartIndex":0,"jtPageSize":100,"jtSorting":"SKU ASC","isMap":"1"} is better way?

Comment: The reason I am asking is that I am doing end to end REST API load testing.In this End to End Testing, GetAllOrderItems() REST API is called many times. If I put JSON Body inside file and then called FileToString , then in future if developer add any new Parameters to GetAllOrderItems() or if any changes happen, then i just need to modify one text file containing JSON body....So, Which is better way for load testing ?

Comment: Then you can use Setup Thread Group to do this loading into a variable , then export it to a property using props.put("key", "value"), then in thread group using User Parameters load the props using ${__P("key")} into a variable

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains nested JMeter Variables you need to wrap your [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function call in [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(${GetAllOrderItems})})}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Eval FileToString]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)